# Conditional ComponentScan on package

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In a Spring Boot Application I have a package with Application class like

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application);
        application.run(args);
    }

}
```

which automatically has ComponentScan set up from that class's package by default. Then I have several subpackages each containing several component and service beans (using annotations). But for the purpose of reuse of this application for different use cases, I need to enable/disable **all** the components in some of the subpackages, preferably by a property.

That is I have subpackages like

```
org.example.app.provider.provider1
org.example.app.provider.provider2
```

Now, based on some property I would like to enable (scan for) beans in one of the packages, e.g.

```
provider1.enabled=true
```

I thought I could make ConditionalOnProperty on Configuration class work like that, but the problem is, that the beans are picked up by the default @SpringBootApplication component scan (i.e. the subpackage Configuration class does not override the top level one)

So I thought I would exclude the packages, but this adds more work (and knowledge) when a new provider package is needed (need to know in advance to add an explicit exclude for that package).

Is there any other way how to do this I can't figure out?

Comment: Does it matter what property you'll use? Because you can do this easily with Spring profiles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Load the provider components conditionally

A Spring Configuration annotated with a `@ConditionalOnProperty` would do just that:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.example.app.provider.provider1")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "provider1.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class Provider1Configuration {
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.example.app.provider.provider2")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "provider2.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class Provider2Configuration {
}
```

#### Then exclude the components under `org.example.app.provider.*`

Now, all you need is to exclude the providers from Spring Boot Application (and let the `CondtionalOnProperty` do its work). You can either:

- (1) move the provider packages so that they are **not below** the Spring Boot Application

For example, if the Spring Boot main is in `org.example.app`, keep the `@Configuration` in `org.example.app` but the providers in `org.example.providers`

- (2) Or exclude the provider package from Spring Boot (assuming the `@Configuration` are in `org.example.app` for example):

**SpringBootMain.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, pattern = "org.example.app.provider.*"))
class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```